# iOS Swift storing simple data globally

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, singleton, plist

New to iOS development and trying to develop my app with correct practices. My main issue is trying to figure out the best way to store a bunch of simple data globally.

The app connects to a computer adhoc wifi and gathers information about the current state. (ex// gpu temp, computer name, display resolution, date/time, etc). The various view controllers I have then allow the user to adjust some of these settings so I want to be able to keep track of these changes across all view controllers.

I have been wrestling between using a plist, core data, or singleton class to store all the information. Since the user will be connected to one computer for the life of the app I am leaning towards singleton since it seems easiest to get and set data. However, I have read that using a singleton is really not the best practice for various reasons. I have read up on plists and core data a little and seems like a decent amount of work just to get and set values. Should I spend the time using those or would some other method be a better way to accomplish all of this.

**Update:**
After both answers from Aaoli and Swift Rabbit. I wanted to clarify for my use case that the data I am storing did not need to be "saved" when the app was closed. So if you are coming to this question and need to store your data even if the app closes look at @SwiftRabbit's answer.

Comment: do you want to store it permanently? or you want to use it globally and when the app dies it rest ?

Comment: I think just globally so if the user closes the app they have to reconnect to computer and "gather" the information again. @AaoIi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use Global variable in Swift you need to define struct outside the class and because you don't need the variable to be swimming in the whole app memory without binding:

```
struct GlobalVar {
    static var myvar = 0

}
```

To use simply the global variable from anywhere use :

```
GlobalVar.myvar = 10
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, using "simple" data, which is not sensitive, I usually use the user defaults. They can be accessed globally through the project. For example, it can be set this way :

```
var prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
prefs.setObject(myValue, forKey: "myKey") // myValue is of type typeOfValue 
prefs.synchronize()
```

It can be accessed this way :

```
var prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
prefs.valueForKey("myKey") as? typeOfValue
```

Using setObject can be used for any kind of value, that's why I cast it when retrieving it from the userDefaults. You could actually use other methods to insert it and retrieve it that would make your task easier. For example, you could tell you are inserting a bool with :

```
prefs.setBool(<#value: Bool#>, forKey: <#String#>)
```

And specify you are retrieving one with :

```
prefs.boolForKey(<#defaultName: String#>)
```

All methods can be found in the apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

Comment: So in terms of writing quality code, is there a downside to @Aaoli's answer, it seems much simpler in terms of its implementation.

Comment: His solution won't save anything. It will just set a global variable in the project. Upon reloading the application, all values will be reset to the default value (in his example myvar = 0)

Comment: @reddman, By using NSUserDefaults your storing data in plist file, but keep in mind that NSUserDefaults is not safe to store sensitive data..

Comment: His solution is definitely better if you don't need to save your data. I wasn't sure in the context you provided.

Comment: Thank you both, I apologize for not adding complete context I will edit the question to include further detail.  I think @Aaoli's answer fits my situation but I believe that Swift Rabbit's answer is equally valuable to me or anyone viewing this question later for future development

Answer (score 2):

My opinion: create a singleton, e.g. in this way:

```
class MyClass {
    /// The singleton instance
    private static var singletonInstance: MyClass!

    class var sharedInstance: MyClass! {
        get {
            singletonInstance = singletonInstance ?? MyClass()
            return singletonInstance
        }
    }

    private init() { }
}
```

Or in this way:

```
class MySingletonClass  {
    static let sharedInstance = MySingletonClass()

    private init() {
}
```

Many people consider Singleton a poor design pattern, but in my opinion it is not. It is good to have a pattern which ensures that a piece of information is only available once. What is not good is to have global access to this Singleton from anywhere in the application. Some people counter-act this with "Dependency Injection", which basically means that your classes does not "pull" the information from the Singleton but the information is "pushed" *into* the class from (some other instance) outside. This promotes loose coupling and better test-ability. But this is an advanced topic which needs much more information. (Google "typhoon framework" for iOS if you are interested in this)

Comment: How would you add and access data from this singleton pattern? Should I add `static var myvar = 0` inside `public init()`, and then access it using `MySingletonClass.myvar` ?

Comment: Not public, but private init. Just create a normal var and access it like this: MySingletonClass.sharedInstance.myvar

Comment: I do get a `Initialization of variable 'myvar' was never used, consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it` warning.  I guess I can just ignore that.

Comment: Initialize it either on creation ( var myvar = 0) or in the private init ( myvar = 0). If you never use it - why did you create it?